# Send an HTML file using Sendmail from Linux server

Tags: linux, shell, html, redhat-enterprise-linux, sendmail

I tried to use this command but it doesn't work from my server. Any suggestion for this case.

```
(
echo "From: ${from}";
echo "To: ${to}";
echo "Subject: ${subject}";
echo "Content-Type: text/html";
echo "MIME-Version: 1.0";
echo "";
echo "${message}";
) | sendmail -t
```

Comment: What exactly means "it doesn't work"? Is there any error message? What is in the mail logs?

Comment: Does Sendmail work at all?

Comment: thank you all i found a solution . its was related just to the path of sendmail